# resultset.first(); doesnt return it to the first row

Tags: java, sql

this is one of my button behaviors.
my problem is resultset.first(); doesnt return the cursor to the first row.
this is my code

```
public void Menu3_next( JTextField jTextField1, JTextField jTextField2, JComboBox jComboBox1, JComboBox jComboBox2){
    Connect();    
    try{
        statement = connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from Menu3");
        resultset.first();
        while(resultset.next()){
            jTextField1.setText(String.format("%s", resultset.getString("idMenu3")));
            jTextField2.setText(String.format("%s", resultset.getString("Name")));
        }
        String query1 = String.format("select * from Menu1");// where idMenu1 = '%s'",strBrand);
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(query1);
        resultset.first();
        while(resultset.next()){
            jComboBox1.addItem(String.format("%s", resultset.getString("Brand")));
        }
        String query2 = String.format("select * from Menu2");// where idMenu= '%s'",strPart);
        resultset = statement.executeQuery(query2);
        resultset.first();
        while(resultset.next()){
            jComboBox2.addItem(String.format("%s", resultset.getString("Part")));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

TIA Guys. when i click the button it must show the next, and next and next, until the last row. but it doesnt. it just show the last row.

Comment: Is there any reason to skip the first row? You're calling `resultset.first()` and then `resultset.next()` so the first accessed result is the second row.

Answer (score 1):

The `while (resultset.next()) { ... }` idiom expects the cursor is *before* the first row. When you call `resultset.first()`, the cursor moves to the first row, and then `resultset.next()` will move the cursor forward again, effectively skipping the first row.

Comment out all the `resultset.first()` statements to fix, for example:

```
resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from Menu3");
//resultset.first();
while (resultset.next()) {
    jTextField1.setText(String.format("%s", resultset.getString("idMenu3")));
    jTextField2.setText(String.format("%s", resultset.getString("Name")));
}
```

Comment: still the same. it still get the last row and display that. btw thanks:3

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the question thoroughly enough and my answer covered another issue I believe... As pointed out in other answers, your issue is with the use of `first()`and `next()` but I do believe the point I made is still valid.

When you don't include an explicit `ORDER BY` the order of the rows in the set returned will be arbitrary. The solution to your problem is most likely to specify the order in the query:

`SELECT * FROM Menu3 ORDER BY ...`

Also, using `select *` is considered a bad practice, see [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) for reasons why (also [Why is SELECT * considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)).

Comment: So the solution for skipped result set entries is an `ORDER BY` statement? Sounds interesting. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Tom No, of course it isn't, and I never claimed that, did I? My answer was meant to point out that rows might not appear in a specific order, and thus it can be perceived as rows being skipped if the first row in a set was expected to appear later. After re-reading the question it seems that the issue here is the use of `first()` and `next()`. The `ORDER BY` still matters in my opinion.

Comment: im using order by and not using first() but still the same :3

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `first()` here.  After you execute a query the `ResultSet` is positioned **before** the first row. Subsequent calls the `next()` will move it forward until there are no more rows.

Your current code has the following steps:

1. Produce `ResultSet` (positioned **before** first row)
2. Call `first()` (positioned on first row)
3. Call `next()` in loop (positioned on second, third, etc row)

   - You do something with that row (the second, third, etc, but not **the first**)

By calling `first()` and subsequent calls to `next()`, you are **skipping the first row**.

You seem to have the idea that the `ResultSet` is the same object during the entire method: it isn't, each call to `executeQuery` produces a **new** `ResultSet`. And as matter of correctly closing resources, you should start using [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) with JDBC resources to make sure the `ResultSet`, `Statement` and `Connection` is closed correctly after you are done with them.

---

As to your second problem: you use `setText`, `setText` replace the entire content of the field. So of course it will only show the last row.

PS On stackoverflow you should stick to one problem per question.